# SQS: How can I read the sent time of an SQS message using Python's boto library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I can see messages have a sent time when I view them in the SQS message view in the AWS console. How can I read this data using Python's boto library?

Answer (score 3):

When you read a message from a queue in boto, you get a `Message` object.  This object has at attribute called `attributes`.  It is a dictionary of attributes that SQS keeps about this message.  It includes `SentTimestamp`.

Comment: I'm finding `attributes` to be and empty `{}` after a `q.get_messages(10)` in boto 2.8.0

Comment: By default, ``get_messages`` does not return any attributes.  You have to specify which attributes you want returned via the ``attributes`` parameter.  This can have a value of: All|SenderId|SentTimestamp|ApproximateReceiveCount|ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp

Comment: I think there is a bug in boto - if you specify specific attributes they will return (ex: SentTimestamp). 'ALL' also returns an empty dict for me.

Comment: Are you using ``ALL`` or ``All``.  The service expects the latter.

Comment: I get the same result: Empty attributes and message_attributes list no matter what.

Comment: The ``attributes`` parameter actually expects a list of attribute names.  I just tried: ``q.get_messages(attributes=['All'])`` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *attributes* parameter of the *get_message()* method. See the [documentation](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/sqs.html#boto.sqs.queue.Queue.get_messages).

```
queue.get_messages(attributes=['All'])
```

The [documentation](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/sqs.html#boto.sqs.queue.Queue.read) also says that you can do this with the *read()* method but this is broken right now. I opened an issue for this on the project site: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2699.